# Can someone tell me what this command does?

Tags: grep, git

I have encountered the following command in an internet tutorial. I couldn't understand how it works.

```
git log | grep commit  > ~/filename.txt
```

Someone please explain me how it works.

Comment: what does the tutorial say about the command line? ... what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Have you tried to find out what `git log` does and what `grep` does?

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? `git` or `grep` or `>` or … Note git is not easy to use, see https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/2897/204

Answer (score 2):

1. `git log` outputs the Git history.
2. The pipe (`|`) instructs the shell to pass the output as a data stream into `grep`.
3. `grep` will extract all the lines containing the string `commit` from the output of `git log`.
4. `>` redirects the result of `grep` to the file `filename.txt` in the home directory (`~`).

Answer (score 0):

You can safely try this out.

Change into a directory with a git repo.  Try "git log" to see what ist does.
( [Git Basics here](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) )

Then do "git log| grep commit" to see what it does.

Then try the entire command and have a look at the file "filename.txt" that will appear in your home directory.

After that, you may want to check the manpages for both [git](https://manpage.me/?q=git) and [grep](https://manpage.me/?q=grep).
And maybe have a look at the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), which is very valuable resource I have made many uses of myself.